# JUnit doesn't scan Jakarta entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, junit4

I have a java(8) application running with Tomcat 10, Spring 5.3.22, hibernate 5.6.10.Final and jakarta.persistence 3.0.0
I'm using jakarta entities due to my tomcat 10.

entity for example:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name="GLOBAL_VALUES")
public class GlobalValueEntry extends BaseEntry {

    private String key;
    private String value;

    public GlobalValueEntry(){
    }

    public GlobalValueEntry(String key, String value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Column(name = "KEY_STRING",unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

My app runs properly meaning the web server is up and I can perform actions such as saving and updating using the entity above but when I try to preform the same action via junit, it fails due to

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.imperva.itp.domain.globalvalues.GlobalValueEntry
```

the junit code:

```
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
    
    import java.util.Date;
    
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/test-config.xml")
    @Transactional
    public class GlobalValueDaoImplTest {
    
        @Autowired
        private GlobalValueDaoImpl globalValueDao;
    
        @Before
        public void cleanUp(){
            globalValueDao.deleteAll(globalValueDao.findAll());
        }
    
        @Test
        public void testSaveSingleGlobalValue(){
            GlobalValueEntry entry = new GlobalValueEntry("testkey","testvalue");
            assertNotNull(globalValueDao.save(entry));
        }
}
```

for some reason, although my hibernate config specify to scan the the package my entity is in, the scan return empty result. ( again only in case of junit, when the tomcat 10 is running the scan returns with a list of all the jakarta entites I have)

this is my hibernate config:

```
   <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
          depends-on="flyway">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="src.entities"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect</prop>
                <prop key="configurationClass">org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${db.username}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

any ideas?

Comment: You cannot use Spring 5.x with Tomcat 10. Nor can you use Hibernate 5.6 with Jakarta Persistence 3.0. Downgrade to Tomcat 9 and Jakarta Persistence 2.2. To use Tomcat 10 and Jakarta Persistence 3.0, you need Spring 6 (not yet released) and Hibernate 6.x.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? If so, can you put a link here please?

Comment: and if Spring doesn't support it, can I add theses entries via the java code in someway?

Comment: Normally this wouldn't be so problematic, but the change from Jakarta EE 8 to Jakarta EE 9 (which includes going from Jakarta Persistence 2.2 to 3.0) changed the package names used by these libraries from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`. Tomcat 10 is basically Tomcat 9, but using the `jakarta` namespace. Spring 5 declares Java EE 7 as the [baseline](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#baseline-update), and also working with Java EE / Jakarta EE 8. This means it doesn't work with Jakarta EE 9.

Comment: As to Spring 6 + `jakarta` namespace, see [A Java 17 and Jakarta EE 9 baseline for Spring Framework 6](https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6). For Hibernate 5.6, technically you can use it with Java Persistence 3.0, provided you use the `*-jakarta` dependencies instead of the normal dependencies. Alternatively, you could upgrade to Hibernate 6, but for both options you might run into issues if you also integrate with Spring (e.g. Spring Data JPA).

Answer (score 0):

Spring does not support Jakarta namespaces yet.

This will be done with Spring 6 and Spring Boot 3.

You have to use the javax namespaces.